# If $P$ is a perfect set and $K$ is compact, what can we say about $P \bigcap K$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I know *compact* $\rightarrow$ *bounded and closed* and so necessarily all sequences in $K$ converge to a point $\in K$.

Set $P$ is *perfect* $\rightarrow$ *closed and contains no isolated points*, which also lends itself to being a closed interval (but not necessarily an interval?)

*(i)* Then the intersection of two closed sets means $P \bigcap K$ is also closed. Could I also make the claim that the intersection is bounded and thus compact?

*(ii)* The intersection $P \bigcap K$ is not necessarily perfect, what I can't see is how to construct a perfect set $P$ and a closed set $K$ so that $P \bigcap K$ contains at least one isolated point.

If someone could point me in the right direction  in the context of basic undergrad real analyisi I would be grateful, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Yes, the intersection is bounded, since $K$ is, and therefore it is compact. For the example that you want, let $P=[0,1]$. Take a sequence in $P$ that converges to $0$, and take for $K$ the points of that sequence together with ... what?

Comment: Is the set $(1+ \dfrac{1} {n} )\bigcap 1$ compact? If so, then $K \bigcap P$ would just consist of {1}. But is the singleton set also perfect?

Comment: @Jabernet: What you’re written doesn’t make sense. Did you mean $$\left\{1+\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}\cup\{1\}\;?$$ That isn’t what I was suggesting, but yes, it’s compact, and the intersection is indeed not perfect, since it consists of nothing but an isolated point.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. I need to learn to be more rigorous in what I write down! Thank you.

Comment: @Jabernet: You’re welcome.